# Silver recovery from sodium hydroxide solution

Tags: solutions

I have washed graphic film with sodium hydroxide solution removing the silver emulsion. Is there any way to now recover the silver from solution?

Comment: You could add salt water and precipitate silver chloride, collect that by filtration and then follow the procedure outlined here https://www.finishing.com/195/29.shtml

Comment: In relatively high alkaline environments, silver precipitates as dark-brown silver oxide with traces of metallic silver. If this sparingly soluble form is still too insoluble for you (due to the low concentration), maybe adding concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ dropwise might help (you don't want to add too much, as it can form the water-soluble complex $\ce{HAgCl2}$).

Comment: A Pourbaix diagram might also be helpful to highlight the species that exist in solution: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Pourbaix-diagram-for-silver-The-graph-shows-the-speciation-of-silver-as-a-function-of_fig1_284173017

Comment: Insoluble silver compounds are not soluble in $\ce{NaOH}$ solutions. If they react, they are transformed into silver oxide $\ce{Ag2O}$ which is a dark brown precipitate.

Answer (score 1):

As @Maurice mentioned in a comment, it is unlikely that you have silver in the solution after washing with $\ce{NaOH}$. In alkali the silver will rapidly form $\ce{Ag2O}$ and this cannot be solved in an excess of $\ce{OH-}$. So I would look for a precipitate.

Instead of washing with NaOH, it is better to use $\ce{NH3}$ instead. This will form a soluble silver complex that you can later make react with acetaldehyde or another aldehyde to recover solid $\ce{Ag}$. This is a very common reaction known as Tollen's test. More info here [Tollen's test](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Aldehydes_and_Ketones/Reactivity_of_Aldehydes_and_Ketones/Tollens_Test). If indeed you have a precipitate, you can also use this method by adding an excess of $\ce{NH3}$ to solve it. Note that $\ce{NH3}$ needs to be handled with care and under a hood.

If what you need is to recover a large amount in the order of kgs, then your best alternative could be to use an electrochemical method. And instead of washing with $\ce{NaOH}$ use an acid solution.

And yes, you can also heat to decompose the oxide or the $\ce{AgCl}$ salt, but this requires high temperatures and it's dangerous if you do not have safety measures in place.

Comment: [Silver nitride](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_nitride) can form if ammonia is too concentrated.

Comment: Yes, but the concentration at which you will form $\ce{ [Ag(NH3)2+]}$ is much lower than what you need for the nitride.

Comment: One must consider chemical costs, but your approach is sound.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Silver can be recovered by heating the silver oxide in a crucible, yielding metallic silver and oxygen by the reaction:

2 Ag2O + heat ----->  4 Ag (metallic) + O2

If you want to go for higher purity, acidify with HCl, which will drop silver as AgCl while other metals, such as copper or iron, remain in solution.

The AgCl precipitate can be washed, dried, and flamed exactly the same way as the oxide with excess baking soda (hydrated NaHCO3).

2 NaHCO3 + heat ----> Na2CO3 + H2O + CO2

4AgCl + 2Na2CO3 ----> 4 NaCl + 2 CO2 + 4 Ag (metallic) + O2

Or, as Maurice$^1$ might have it:

4 AgCl + 2 Na2O ----> 4 NaCl + 4 Ag (metallic) + O2

However, the potential of **extremely hazardous** HCl$^2$ or Cl2 fumes as a side reaction exists.  This step should be done outdoors or in a fume hood.

$^1$ thanks for the input.  2 Ag2O to elemental 4 Ag and O2 balances, and the major reaction yields metallic silver and NaCl.

$^2$ several MSDS sheets list an HCl fume hazard under fire fighting procedures.  This may be attributed to AgCl reacting with water to form Silver oxide (AgCl has low water solubility) and HCl.

Comment: Silver chloride cannot be flamed. It melts at $455°$C and boils without decomposition at $1550°$C

Comment: @Maurice um, I've done it.  Try a little baking soda along with it. You'll get HCl off and silver carbonate to silver oxide to silver.  BTW AgCl decomposes to metallic silver and Cl2 in the presence of light.

Comment: It is impossible to produce $\ce{HCl}$ when heating anything mixed with soda. $\ce{HCl}$ destroys soda.

Comment: @ Robert DiGiovanni. I have been specialized in and teaching practical inorganic chemistry during all my life. And I perfectly know about Le Chatelier's principle. I have carried out (a lot of times) calcinations of products with soda ($\ce{Na2CO3}$). I know that it can produce some gas, but this gas is never $\ce{HCl}$. Never ! Another information : When soda is heated to T >> 1000°C, it is decomposed into $\ce{Na2O + CO2}$, but it does not produce $\ce{NaOH}$ as you state.

Comment: @Maurice appreciate your comments.  Some of the chemistry may seem a bit unorthodox, but silver + is a voracious seeker of electrons.  Water (oxygen) becomes a *reducing agent* (or in its forms NaOH, Na2O). With outgassing, I remain convinced there are hazards from side reactions.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of mistakes in this message ! $1$) $\ce{NaOH}$ will never coexist with $\ce{NaHCO3}$. Both will react according to : $$\ce{NaOH + NaHCO3 -> Na2CO3 + H2O}$$ $2$) Furthermore, at T > $290$°C, $\ce{NaHCO3}$  becomes $\ce{Na2CO3}$ $$\ce{2 NaHCO3 -> Na2CO3 + H2O + CO2}$$ So $\ce{NaHCO3}$ will never occur under a propane torch. $3$) $\ce{Cl2}$ will never be emitted out of a hot mixture containing $\ce{NaOH}$. $\ce{Cl2}$ will react with $\ce{NaOH}$ and produce $\ce{NaCl + NaClO3}$ $$\ce{6 NaOH + 3 Cl2 -> NaClO3 + 5 NaCl + 3 H2O}$$ and $\ce{NaClO3}$ may lose its $3$ O atoms at high T values